# Do we want Hebrew in tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, hebrew

As of recently, tags can now be any (Unicode) character (not just 7-bit alphanumeric characters), with that feature being turned on only for sites that request it: and that request must be well-thought-out (viz, must include a plan of how the feature will be used).

Do we want this feature? If so, what shall we do with it? Please post propositions as answers here so that others may up- or downvote them.

Comment: An earlier version of this question: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1420.

Answer (score 8):

The site uses English, so IMO its tags should use the English alphabet, even if that means using transliterations. This probably also improves search-engine findability.

The only use of the new feature thus would be for [tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710). IMO that's a good use for it, and we should request the feature with planned use restricted to synonyms.

*Edit:* I didn't specify *why* I think synonyms are a good use for the new feature. It's because some people can easily type Hebrew and will do so when choosing a tag instead of trying to guess at a transliteration that might appear as the tag.

Comment: I agree, it would be nice to have a synonym in hebrew, thus eliminating the transliteration problems.

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/679 and its answers.

Comment: We can't restrict the non-ASCII tags to synonyms only. That's something you guys would need to stay on top of if you want them to be only used that way.

Comment: @AnnaLear IMO we're capable of staying on top of it.

Comment: @AnnaLear, that's what I meant by this answer (though I can't speak for its upvoters), and I agree with DoubleAA's comment just above. Thanks for stopping by and paying attention to this.

Comment: @AnnaLear Has SE considered this proposal?

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes - it's something we enable or we don't, and I don't believe we have right-to-left support in tags (not sure if you could make that work). So, if enabled, it'd be up to you if you're going to use it just for synonyms, etc. It's _not_ a particularly expensive thing to have turned on, but if you think it might cause a bit of chaos by being accessible to anyone that can create tags, it might be better to leave off.